# Monitoring Openshift Jenkins Gear via CCTray

Tags: jenkins, redhat, openshift, cruisecontrol, cctray

I've managed to modify CCTray using a transport extension to connect to a local Jenkins server running on my locahost. I cannot however connect to the openshift remote jenkins server which has been setup on my account.

I can access it correctly from the Openshift Jenkins Web URL however I can't connect to it using the CCTray transport extension, it just times out. I think it's because it tries to connect to the actual port the Jenkins server is running on and this is being blocked.

Would installing and running the client tools/ssh comms fix this problem?

Or is this impossible to do. It is a very nice notifications tray program so would be great to get it working.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So openshift only has 80 and 443 open externally and so if CCtray is trying to connect to the port itself then it won't be get to it. Can you configure CCtray to use the public URL to interact with Jenkins?